# Is it reasonable to overload operators by ref-qualifier to prevent temporaries?

Tags: c++, ref-qualifier

It just occurred to me that `operator+` & co can operate on `this` for rvalues; i.e. given a class `C`, it's possible to do this:

```
class C {
    // ...
    C operator-( const C& rhs ) const & {
        C result = *this;
        result -= rhs;
        return result;
    }
    C&& operator-( const C& rhs ) && {
        *this -= rhs;
        return std::move( *this );
    }
};
```

This would prevent copies by simply modifying temporary values in-place.

Would this perform as I expect? Is it a reasonable optimization or would the compiler create equally fast code?

Comment: With the first version you can already get copy ellision. So I'm not sure the second one is needed (if it works at all, I feel like it would bite you in the ass but I could be wrong)

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling that copy elision might lead to similar performance... But I don't see how my version could bite me in the ass quite yet. (I'm not sure though, hence the question.)

Comment: Object lifetime issues. `C&& c = C() - some_C;` and `c` is dangling.

Comment: You appear to be right. I don't quite understand why yet.

Comment: @T.C. You can declare objects to be of rvalue-type? Why? Is that useful for anything? (E.g. why not just `C c = .... ; use_ctype(std::move(c));` ?)

Comment: @KyleStrand Suspend the temporary in mid-air and extend its lifetime if it's of a non-movable type. You rarely need this explicitly, but the range-based for loop does it internally.

Comment: Huh. Okay, so when you say that `c` is dangling, is that just because it's now a "moved-from" value? Other than that, I don't quite see why the code will be problematic....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say we just wrap `std::string` and do a simplified version of `operator+`:

```
struct C { 
    std::string val;

    C&& operator+(const C& rhs) && {
        val += rhs.val;
        return std::move(*this);
    }   

    std::string::iterator begin() { return val.begin(); }
    std::string::iterator end() { return val.end(); }
};
```

With that, this works fine:

```
for (char c : C{"hello"}) { .. }
```

the range-for expression will extend the lifetime of the temporary, so we're ok. However, consider this:

```
for (char c : C{"hello"} + C{"goodbye"}) { .. }
```

We effectively have:

```
auto&& __range = C{"hello"}.operator+(C{"goodbye"});
```

Here, we're not binding a temporary to a reference. We're binding a reference. The object doesn't get its lifetime extended because... it's not an object. So we have a dangling reference, and undefined behavior. This would be very surprising to users who would expect this to work:

```
for (char c : std::string{"hello"} + std::string{"goodbye"}) { .. }
```

You'd have to return a value:

```
C operator+(const C& rhs) && {
    val += rhs.val;
    return std::move(*this);
}
```

That solves this issue (as now we have temporary extension), and if moving your objects is cheaper than copying them, this is a win.